# Python selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable on Ubuntu 20.04 terminal

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to run Chrome via selenium in python.  I keep getting this stack trace dump and selenium saying Message: chrome not reachable.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_sel.py", line 20, in <module>
    do_ss()
  File "test_sel.py", line 16, in do_ss
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
  File "/home/ro1423/sel/sel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/ro1423/sel/sel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/home/ro1423/sel/sel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 275, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/ro1423/sel/sel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 365, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/ro1423/sel/sel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ro1423/sel/sel_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
#0 0x558795d20c33 <unknown>
#1 0x558795a69fef <unknown>
#2 0x558795a58209 <unknown>
#3 0x558795a90b09 <unknown>
#4 0x558795a8ca04 <unknown>
#5 0x558795a88dea <unknown>
#6 0x558795ac3dfa <unknown>
#7 0x558795abdf23 <unknown>
#8 0x558795a938aa <unknown>
#9 0x558795a94a05 <unknown>
#10 0x558795d651ed <unknown>
#11 0x558795d6924e <unknown>
#12 0x558795d4f48e <unknown>
#13 0x558795d69f88 <unknown>
#14 0x558795d44630 <unknown>
#15 0x558795d86308 <unknown>
#16 0x558795d86488 <unknown>
#17 0x558795da083d <unknown>
#18 0x7fdc42950609 <unknown>
```

This is all I am trying to do:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def do_ss():
    browser = None
    service = Service(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
    options = Options()
    options.binary_location='/usr/bin/google-chrome'
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
 #   options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
#    options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    browser.quit()
do_ss()
```

After about a minute or so thinks just dump.

Whenever I run Chrome from CLI like this:

```
google-chrome --no-sandbox --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-dev-shm-usage
```

I get:

```
[0519/150706.580894:ERROR:filesystem_posix.cc(63)] mkdir /tmp/Crashpad/new: Permission denied (13)
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, is your chromedriver the same version as the chrome on your pc?

Comment: Google Chrome is 101.0.4951.64  and chromedriver is 101.0.4951.41.

Comment: Hi @user982599 I am running ito this issue as well, except with chromedriver/chrome on 104.x.x.x. Did you find out how to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, no I did not.  I moved to using Firefox and Gecko Driver for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

the /tmp/Crashpad directory is where Chrome stores crash dumps by default. When they're created, they are created as the user that ran the python app. if you run the same app or chromedriver on the same machine as a different user you get the error you posted above. You can change the directory where the crashdumps are stored by adding this:

```
crashpad_directory = '/path/to/my/crashpad'
options = Options()
options.add_argument(f'--crash-dumps-dir={crashpad_directory}')
```

or if you don't care about the crash dumps:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-crash-reporter')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things that might help.

First of all, you have to be sure your *umask* setting allows Chrome to create files and directories, e.g. umask 002.

Secondly, Chrome sometimes installs a file in */etc/cron.daily* that causes Chrome to be updated automatically every day.  The problem is that this causes Chrome to be a different version than *chromedriver*.  So you end up with a selenium app that works for a few weeks, and then suddenly stops working.

Thirdly, I had a lot of trouble getting Chrome to work in headless mode, and I ended up just running Chrome normally, but with *xvfb*, which is a dummy terminal driver.